# Confused about salesforce repository on bitbucket

Tags: mavensmate

I am bit confused about repository on bitbucket. So we have one production, one sandbox. We do development on sandbox and we are provided with a repo to clone. There are other branches as well for QA, UAT etc.

The question is when they setup bitbucket intitially, was it like they fetched production metadata and kept on that master branch? From this repo they should have created other branches for qa, cat etc?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, yes, most organizations choose to just start with a code dump from production and put it directly in the `master` branch. This is probably not the best solution, but it is the fastest solution. A better solution would be to build the repo up one feature at a time by pulling in pieces. Unfortunately, this is time-consuming and somewhat error prone as of yet. Ideally, you'd start from a clean DX scratch org, copy features in one at a time, and build up the repo.

There really isn't just "one right way" or even "one best way"; each method you might use has advantages and disadvantages. You might want to start with the [dreamhouse dx](https://github.com/forcedotcom/sfdx-dreamhouse) for how one might use DX to set up a repo, as well as the [trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/unlocked-packages-for-customers/units/build-your-first-unlocked-package) that goes with it. The examples use GitHub, but BitBucket is similar in functionality (both use the underlying "git" protocol). I hope I've given you enough information to get started, but you will need to take some time to understand everything involved.

Also, I found [this blog post](https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) (not my own) incredibly useful for understanding Git better, and our own internal design is loosely based on this model.

Answer (score 1):

This question might be seen off the topic as implementing  CI/CD in salesforce using BitBucket is not uniform across businesses. A good setup with SF CI/CD, I have seen had Production, Full Sandbox (UAT) where staging and testing were done, shared developer sandbox where integration was done, and an individual developer sandbox for each developer.

A git repo that maps to each of these orgs production repo then Forks. With a staging fork for our UAT environment and then a dev fork that maps to the dev
environment and these are all exact copies of each other and then using Forks allows having different repository level permissions for each repo and then also allows for sinking downward fork sinking which is helpful when doing changes directly in production and wants to have those reflected down into the other sandboxes

Further on into the dev process, there was one feature branch for each discrete peach piece of functionality or a bug fix. How BitBucket pipeline is set up in the cloud, code changes are made, conducting code reviews, working with branches, JIRA integration, deployments are out of scope and one can easily gain such info from Atlassian.